# How to vary the density of instances within a mesh volume in geo nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, volumetrics

What I want is to alter the 'density' of instances within a mesh volume, I don't believe there's a way to directly do this, but I'm instead attempting to translate the instances to mimic the effect.

At the moment I'd be satisfied to create a dense area in the centre of the 'cylinder' getting sparser towards the outside.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/mWjmyy6]

I've been working on transferring the normals of the volume cylinder to the instances, and then multiplying the normals  by the proximity to said cylinder (via *Geometry Proximity*) albeit it's not quite working as intended.

Are there other methods of possibly doing this?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Did you also create the particles/instances with *Geometry Nodes*? ...Maybe it would be good if you share your blend file with us: https://blend-exchange.com/